# Azure Web App for Containers managed identity and non-web applications

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-web-app-for-containers

We are looking for a way to deploy one or two long-running containers in Azure. after considering ACI (more suitable for short lived workloads) and AKS (too much overhead for running a single container?) we've decided to go with [Azure Web App for Containers](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/containers/)
We are left with the following questions on this service:

1. **Non-web containers** - Is it suitable for running generic non-web application containers? for example, can it listen and expose ports/protocols other than http/s, can it run cron jobs that trigger an outbound non-http TCP connection?
2. **Managed identity** - Will the container be able to leverage managed identity set for the app service, for example to access Azure Key Vault secrets, or other PaaS services that support MI?

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, thank you. marked as answered.

Comment: I'm not sure about the ability to run cron (there is one example of running multi-container solution with an internal facing Mysql server, so I don't see a reason why cron won't work) , but I've read the FAQ and indeed this service is limited to http/s ports, which is not appropriate for my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Non-web containers - Is it suitable for running generic non-web application containers? for example, can it listen and expose
>    ports/protocols other than http/s, can it run cron jobs that trigger
>    an outbound non-http TCP connection?

No, Azure Web App only can expose on port and it must be one of 80 and 443. And as I know, it's not suitable to run cron jobs.

> 2. Managed identity - Will the container be able to leverage the managed identity set for the app service, for example, to access Azure
>    Key Vault secrets or other PaaS services that support MI?

Yes, Azure Web App support Managed Identity to access other resources such as Azure Key Vault secrets that support the Managed Identity.

Comment: Finally had the time to test it and so far there are my findings:
1. Non-web containers and cron jobs are supported.
2. Managed identity doesn't seem to work with custom container images. checking this issue with Azure support.

Comment: @SetecAstronomy Are you sure about that? As I know the MSI in the Azure web app is set as the environment variables, not inside the container, so the custom image does not matter. Take a look at this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=dotnet#obtain-tokens-for-azure-resources).

Comment: Not sure I understand your last comment. On the link you referenced it says: "An app with a managed identity has two environment variables defined:
IDENTITY_ENDPOINT - the URL to the local token service..."
However when connecting to the custom container hosted on the App service, this env variable is not exported, so token cannot be obtained.

Comment: Managed identity issue resolved and it is supported. more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65451162/using-azure-web-app-for-containers-with-managed-identity/65481922#65481922